# Insert form data into database glitch

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Alright so I am currently trying to make a system to take applications and it was working until I added the rest of the questions :

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');

$user =$_POST['username'];
$job =$_POST['job'];
$active =$_POST['active'];
$why =$_POST['Q1']
$le =$_POST['Q2']
$skype =$_POST['skype']

if(mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO app (username,job,active,why,le,skype) VALUES ('$user','$job','$active','$why','$le','$skype')"))
echo"successfully inserted";
else
echo "failed";
?>
```

But when I have it like that I get this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$le' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\app_insert.php on line 8

Keep in mind I am using xampp with Apache and Mysql, anyone know whats happening?

Comment: `PHP` needs semi-colon at the end of each instruction line, Which is called [Instruction separation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)

Answer (score -1):

You missed out the semi-colon, `;` for:

```
$why =$_POST['Q1']
$le =$_POST['Q2']
$skype =$_POST['skype']
```

It should be:

```
$why =$_POST['Q1'];
$le =$_POST['Q2'];
$skype =$_POST['skype'];
```

Comment: There is no need to answer such simple questions. You may use comments for this kind of purposes.

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the semi-colon and the insert SQL statement seems incorrect. You are passing the string to SQL statements instead of the value

```
<?php
include_once('db.php');

$user =$_POST['username'];
$job =$_POST['job'];
$active =$_POST['active'];
$why =$_POST['Q1'];
$le =$_POST['Q2'];
$skype =$_POST['skype']

if(mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO app (username,job,active,why,le,skype) VALUES ('{$user}','{$job}','{$active}','{$why}','{$le}','{$skype}')"))
echo"successfully inserted";
else
echo "failed";
?>
```

Comment: There is no need to answer such simple questions. You may use comments for this kind of purposes.